# PHP mail returns true (Message accepted for delivery), but the message is not sent

Tags: php, email, ubuntu-server

I have been trying get php to send mail for over a month. I am moving from 000webhost, where it worked fine, to my friend's server.

The php code that sends mail is:

```
$subject = $u.", your infomation";  
$message = "Your password is ".$p;  
$from = "me@gmail.com";  
$headers = "From:" . $from;  
if(mail($e,$subject,$message,$headers))  
$_SESSI ON['message']="message sent";  
else $_SESSION['message']="error";
```

---

the sendmail path in php.ini is   "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"

---

etc/hosts:

```
000.000.000.000 inspiron-1000 inspiron-1000.
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

---

and the mail.log:

```
Jun 9 22:05:07 inspiron-1000 sendmail[24552]: r5A357t5024552: from=www-data, size=144, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201306100305.r5A357t5024552@inspiron-1000.>, relay=www-data@localhost
Jun 9 22:05:07 inspiron-1000 sm-mta[24553]: r5A357A8024553: from=<www-data@inspiron-1000>, size=367, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201306100305.r5A357t5024552@inspiron-1000.>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=ip6-localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jun 9 22:05:08 inspiron-1000 sendmail[24552]: r5A357t5024552: to=user@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30144, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (r5A357A8024553 Message accepted for delivery)
```

---

this is mailq:
    MSP Queue status...

```
/var/spool/mqueue-client is empty
        Total requests: 0
MTA Queue status...
        /var/spool/mqueue (5 requests)
-----Q-ID----- --Size-- -----Q-Time----- ------------Sender/Recipient-----------
r5M3LmZV023863*      19 Fri Jun 21 22:21 <www-data@inspiron-1000>
                     <user@gmail.com>
r5M3HicX023780*      19 Fri Jun 21 22:17 <www-data@inspiron-1000>
                     <user@gmail.com>
r5M3BSDF023465       19 Fri Jun 21 22:11 <www-data@inspiron-1000>
                 (Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.goo)
                     <user@gmail.com>
r5M36Tjx023175       19 Fri Jun 21 22:06 <www-data@inspiron-1000>
                 (Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.goo)
                     <user@gmail.com>
r5M33YQf023137*      19 Fri Jun 21 22:03 <www-data@inspiron-1000>
                 (Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.goo)
                     <user@gmail.com>
        Total requests: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I fixed it:
Install [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Here is a tutorial [how to send mail with PHP mailer](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';

function sendmail($to,$subject, $body) 
{ 
    return sendmailfrom($to,"myemail@gmail.com","from me", $subject, $body);
}
function sendmailfrom($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) 
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';//required for gmail
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';//the email I want to send from  
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';  //my password         
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) return false;
    else return true;
}
?>
```

When ever I want to send mail I include this code, via `include("filename.php")`, and run `sendmail($to,$subject, $body);`

Answer (score 0):

That isn't all of the information from mail.log. You're seeing that the local server did accept your email, but it doesn't mention trying to send that email off to GMail. You could check the mail that is queued for delivery with `$ mailq` from the commandline. Chances are there are a few more lines in that log file with more information though.

Comment: As you can see, the messages you've tried to send are queued up and timing out. This may mean that a firewall is blocking your connection to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.goo. Once again, check those logs, and check if sendmail is configured to send externally (it may have been set up for internal only). You could also try [connecting to that server through telnet](http://drewsymo.com/how-to/smtp-telnet-example-commands-examples-for-smtp-telnet-testing/), and if that fails, it is a firewall/connectivity issue.

Comment: So the problem is definitely in sendmail and not hosts?

Comment: Well your /etc/hosts probably shouldn't point your hostname to 0.0.0.0, but I don't think that is the problem here. There are quite a few things it could be, so you should check each of the possibilities I mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: I get the status code of 220 when I used telnet localhost 25, but it gets stuck on '500 5.5.1 Command unrecognized: ""'. I still can't send mail.

Comment: The fact alone that you get a 220 shows that SMTP isn't blocked and you can send email from the server. Time for you to look at your mail server settings. Ask your friend how things are configured and check things like mail server blacklists and DNS settings. Now that we've answered why PHP claims to send an email that never arrives, you should take a few days and learn about the intricacies of email. You'll probably figure things out without any more help :)

Comment: Would you recommend any sites?

Comment: Start with Google and go from there. You have quite a bit to learn about it, and you'll need multiple sites to make sense of it all.