# how can set bounce back email phpmailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, email-bounces

I am making a email marketing system in which I am sending emails in bulk and there are chances to bounce some emails. I need a solution so that all the email addresses which are spelt incorrectly or failed to send due to any error, should back into the specified address.
Please help me how can I meet these requirements with phpmailer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check this post, hope it will help to do your further process

[PHP mail returns true (Message accepted for delivery), but the message is not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245657/php-mail-returns-true-message-accepted-for-delivery-but-the-message-is-not-se)

if not delivered then you can update your db "undelivered" status for the particular email or send another mail to your inbox about this issues.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need phpmailer specific solution, like how can I set a return path email address so that bounce emails arrived on that specified email address.